# How to remove a blank page from generated docx through "docxtemplater"

Tags: angularjs, docxtemplater

**Description**: Using "docxtemplateer" I have generated a ".docx" in my angularjs app and could see all the data populated. But there is a page which will get render based on a specific condition. And if that condition fails then it's generating a blank page.

**Actual output**: It's adding a blank page.
Expected output: If the page is blank then it should not be generated or removed.

**Initial Analysis**: I have tried searching and gone through the "docxtemplater" but could not find any reference. It might be possible that I have missed something to check.

For ref: [Docxtemplate documentation](https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Any inputs are most welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: The issue has been fixed by removing the conditional tag before the line break to the previous page.

For e.g:

In my case, there was a conditional tag which was added in the new page as below:

```
(linebreak)
{#number_of_items_failed_to_deliver > 0}
    Contents goes here ...
{/}
```

So, as a fix, I have moved this into the just previous page before the line break. So when this conditional fails it didn't get executed and hence blank page was not generated.

Like this :

```
{#number_of_items_failed_to_deliver > 0}
(linebreak)
    Contents goes here ...
{/}
```

Comment: How can I miss to thanks "Edgar". Yes, he is the one who helps me to fix above issue. Thanks a lot, Edgar!